# Visualforce : Lookup field Event

Tags: lookup, event

I have a lookup field declared as below:

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!Product2.Opportunity__c}" id="prodoppr"/>
```

wish to know how to add or handle event for this lookup field? When there is a change in the value I want to trigger method to perform certain validation and upate other fields....how can i achieve this? please any inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`apex:actionSupport`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm) to listen for changes and respond accordingly. For example:

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!Product2.Opportunity__c}" id="prodoppr">
    <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!validateandupdate}" reRender="form" />
</apex:inputfield>
```

If you want to do client-side validation, you can also use [`apex:inputField`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm)'s `onchange` attribute to support listening for changes to the lookup field.

---

Edit: The `action` attribute is used to determine the function to call. So, in this example, the function is named `validateAndUpdate`, which would look like this:

```
public void validateAndUpdate() {
    if(...) { // Some validations
        ApexPages.addMessage(...);
    } else {
        update someRecords;
    }
}
```

Appropriate error handling should also be part of such a function to avoid partial transactions by way of Database.setSavePoint and Database.rollback.

Comment: hi - could u provide some input on how to handle this in the controller class pls?

Comment: @PrabhuSethupathy I provided a very simple example for you.